# Automount any usb on linux (Without using UUID)

Tags: command-line, usb-drive, automounting, yocto

I am trying to get my linux system (only accessible by the command line) to have plug and play usb functionality. I've found many threads about automounting etc, but all of them require an UUID or something similar to get the auto mount to work. This beats the whole plug and play goals as I do not know which flash drive is going to be connected in the usb-port.

I'm trying to auto mount /dev/adb1 to /mnt/usb when a flash drive is connected. For example Raspbian automatically mounts a flash drive in dev/adb1 to /media/pi/, is there a way to change this mount point to /mnt/usb/

Eventually i need to get this working on a yocto build

Comment: What you want is a UDEV rule, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/juancarlospaco/7f4eab1b6899c55ea90dc0ef5eea965d)

Comment: Thanx FelixJN this has gotten me started properly